# Hanging polling GPIO

Tags: c, linux, embedded

I have implemented this function to poll a GPIO switch, and to light up an LED when recording is in progress. The switch is used to start recording. The LED is turned off when recording ends. 
I've found that the code works for short periods of time in between activating the switch. However, if I leave the program running for long periods of time.. the switch starts to lose functionality. As in, I cannot start/stop recording anymore when I flip the switch.

So say I start recording, then wait for a long period of time, maybe 1/2 hour. When I switch to "Off", it doesn't register. 
However, if I do a cat ../gpio57/value, it gives me 0. (1 is recording)

What could be the problem here?

```
void* pollGPIOSwitch(void* arg) {

   //pthread_detach(pthread_self()); 
   Vn200* vn200 = (Vn200*)arg;
   int fd, LEDFd;
   char buf[100];
   char LEDbuf[100];
   char value; 
   int videoRecError;
   bool videoRecOn = false;

   sprintf(buf, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio57/value");
   //printf(buf);

   while (KEEP_GOING) {
       fd = open(buf,O_RDONLY);
       lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET); // -- move to beginning of file
       read(fd,&value,1);
       if (value=='0') {
           printf("Switch is OFF\n");
           if (videoRecOn) { // -- recording on, switch off, end recording
               stopAllRecordings();
               videoRecOn = false;
               TriggerGPSINSThreadExit = 0; // -- reset variables
               printf("Reset GPSINS Thread variables.\n");
               // -- Set LED to off
               sprintf(LEDbuf, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio56/value");
               //printf(LEDbuf);
               LEDFd = open(LEDbuf, O_WRONLY);
               write(LEDFd,"0",2);

           }
       }
       else if (!videoRecOn) { // -- recording off, switch on, start recording
           printf("Switch is ON\n"); 
           if (pthread_create(&GPSINSLoggingThread, NULL, runGPSINS,(void*) vn200) != 0) {
                printf("Error: Fail to create runGPSINS thread\n");
            }

            videoRecError = startVideoRecording();
            if (videoRecError == -1)
                pthread_exit(&videoRecError);
            videoRecOn = true; 
             // -- Set LED to on
             sprintf(LEDbuf, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio56/value");
             //printf(LEDbuf);
             LEDFd = open(LEDbuf, O_WRONLY);
             write(LEDFd,"1",2);

       }
       //fflush(stdout);
       usleep(500000);
   }
   close(fd);
   close(LEDFd);


   printf("Exited Polling!");
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but there's no need to `lseek()` in a file that you've just opened, it's going to be positioned at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
close(fd);
```

*outside* the loop that does the `open()`. I think you're leaking file descriptors like crazy, which eventually leads to `open()` failing, which you're not detecting. Always error-check your I/O.

Perhaps the `lseek()` implies that you wanted to do the `open()` *once* before the loop.

Comment: Doh! Thanks... I am embarrased.